# Java mail fails on Marshmallow and above, but succeeds on Lollipop and below

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail

I build an APP to send a short message through Java mail API with a guide from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/8646755) . It works on my android 5.0.2 phone. But when I deploy it on android 6 or higher, it always failed on authentication. 
There is no special change for mail setting compared with the guide mentioned above. I list some of them for information.

```
    public MailSender(String user, String password, String mailhost) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
    Log.i("SMTP_mail", mailhost);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    session.setDebug(true);
}
```

Also, I added permissions check at runtime with a new request from API 23.

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                4);
    }
```

And AndroidManifest.xml is as following:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

With help from the guide for debugging JavaMail, I collect the logs for success and failure.
**Success on Android 5:**
[image]

**And failure on Android 6:**
[image]

The app code is the same for these two logs except the platforms are different.
Also I notice that there are some certificate failure seen on android 6 log, but from stackoverview search, it seems not a big deal. I am not sure whether it impact anything.

> E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7ba1e98480 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7ba1cfbc98 arg=0x0
>                  ssl=0x7ba1e98480 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   I/System.out: gba_cipher_suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Could anyone help with this issue? It bothers me for several days. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: do you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: I didnt quite get your question . Do you want send mail from your android app?

Comment: You're using an ancient version of JavaMail, and the debug output above has exposed your (encoded but not encrypted) password, CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD IMMEDIATELY!  Then upgrade to the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) and if it still fails update your post.  Although, I don't see why it would fix the problem since it seems to be the server that is rejecting your login attempt, but you should upgrade anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for kindly remind, @Bill Shannon. I changed the password. But for this app, it need to support old android phone like android 4.0. The latest Java mail need at least android 4.4. For server rejecting, I am curious why it succeeded with andrid 5 but failed with android 6. Is there other way to help continue to troubleshoot?

Comment: It's the server that's rejecting your login attempt.  There's nothing in the debug output that suggests why it might be rejecting it.  It's possible that there's a lower level networking problem that's causing it.  Perhaps a difference in the SSL/TLS parameters being used?  Maybe the password is being sent in two network packets instead of one, and that's triggering a bug in the server?  It's hard to say without more information from the server side. Try using a different server just to find out if the problem is specific to smtp.mail.yahoo.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get the reason why “535 5.7.1 Authentication failed” was reported. It is so unexpected because of the pre-installed ime of the device Meizu Note3(m3 note) with Flyme 6.3.0.2A. After I change to google ime and type password again, the email could work successfully. It is so sad for this reason which cost a lot of time to troubleshooting and end with a so tricky tiny point.

Thanks for all guys for comments and suggestions for this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **INTERNET** permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thanks, Nikhil. I add it also in AndroidManifest.xml. It sitll doesn't work.